# Check to see if scanf is not a float

Tags: c

```
#define maximum 100 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    float sum, mean, variance, difference;
    float sumforvariance, standarddev;
    sumforvariance=0;
    sum=0;
    mean=0;
    variance=0;
    difference=0;
    standarddev=0;

    int a, count, b, c;
    float insertnum[maximum]

    for (a=0; a<maximum; a++) {
            scanf("%f",&insertnum[a]);
            count ++;

            if (insertnum[a]==35.00) {

                    if (count==1) {
                            printf ("no data\n");
                            return 0;
                    }
                    break; 

                }

    }

    for (b=0; b<count; b++) {
            sum+=insertnum[b];
    }
    mean=sum/count;

    for (c=0; c<count; c++) {
            difference=insertnum[c]-mean;
            sumforvariance=sumforvariance+pow(difference,2);
    }
    variance=variance/count;
    standarddev=sqrt(variance);

    printf("mean: %f",mean);
    printf("standdev: %f",standarddev);
```

Hi so I have a simple question. I am trying to calculate a standard deviation and mean for a set of numbers like this 
 ./a.out 12 20 30  etc #
The # is to terminate inputing more numbers. As you can see in the first for     loop, I am trying to input the numbers from standard output into an array of floats. The problem is when I enter 35, I do not want to terminate inputting more numbers because its not equal to #. How am I able to enter 35 and continue to enter more numbers until I enter # since they both contain the same numerical value. #=35 and 35=35.

Comment: "I am trying to input the numbers from standard output into an array of floats." --> Not quite.  Code is reading from "standard input" or `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

Read you user input in as a string.  Sniff for the terminating condition, then convert from string to float.  Using the helper function, `strtof` which is available from `#include <stdlib.h>`

```
#define maximum 100 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float sum, mean, variance, difference;
    float sumforvariance, standarddev;
    sumforvariance = 0;
    sum = 0;
    mean = 0;
    variance = 0;
    difference = 0;
    standarddev = 0;

    int a, count=0, b, c;

    float insertnum[maximum];

    for (a = 0; a < maximum; a++) {

        char userinput[101] = {0};
        userinput[0] = '\0';

        scanf("%100s", userinput);

        if (userinput[0] == '#')
        {
            break;
        }
        insertnum[count] = strtof(userinput, nullptr);
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you forgot to initialize `count`. And your code was inserting the `#` read into the array as well. So I fixed that for you.

Aside - I'll never forget the day my computer science professor passionately screamed to the class about the dangers of "reading numbers" from input.  Users type *characters* with the keyboard not *numbers*. Hence, "validating input" became engrained with me to this day.  You might want to consider just letting your loop break whenever the user types anything not a number.  A modified version of the loop as follows:

```
for (a = 0; a < maximum; a++) {
    char userinput[101] = {0};
    userinput[0] = '\0';
    scanf("%100s", userinput);
    char* endptr = NULL;

    float f = strtof(userinput, &endptr);
    if (userinput == endptr)
    {
        // whatever was typed was not a float
        break;
    }
    insertnum[count] = f;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `scanf` -- when it successfully converts a `float` it will return 1 (or more generally, however many conversions in the format string succeeded).  So when the input is `#`, it will return 0 (nothing converted) and leave the `#` on in the input stream.  You can then check the next character to make sure its a `#`.  So you end up with a loop like:

```
for (a=0; a<maximum && scanf("%f",&insertnum[a]) == 1; a++) {
    ++count;
}
```

or even

```
for (count=0; count < maximum && scanf("%f",&insertnum[count]) == 1; ++count);
if (count == maximum) {
    // read the limit -- may be more data
} else {
    if (getchar() == '#') {
        // got the expected terminator
    } else {
        // something else caused a problem
```